# Different Scaling Options for Same Monitor

Tags: display, hdmi, resolution

I have two identical Dell U2718Q monitors (3840 x 2160).

They are both plugged in with two identical HDMI cables to a 15" 2017 MBP running Mojave 10.14.6 via two identical "USB-C to Digital AV" adapters.

When I go to the display settings to and select "Scaled" for each, I get two different sets of options for the "Larger Text / More Space" icons:

- 1280x720
- 1920x1080
- 2560x1440
- 3200x1800
- 3840x2160

And the other monitor gives me:

- 1920x1080
- 2650x1440
- 3008x1692
- 3360x1890
- 3840x2160

It obviously sees both monitors have the same maximum resolution.  Why would each monitor give me different scaling options?  How can I make them consistent?